# Wanting to make weather app glow different colors depending on time

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to make my weather app glow "yellow" between the hours of 6 to 16 and "purple" outside of those hours. I have given the element classes of am and pm, and added the styling in CSS for each class. The problem I encounter is in JavaScript. I created a function called "glow" and when I use .classList.add, it is only recognizing one of the classes (the last class name I add in html-which is pm) and not the other one(am). I provided a snippet of my HTML and JS below.
(Ps. I am using bootstrap)

HTML

```
 <body>
    <div id="weather-app-wrapper">
      <div class="container-lg mt-5 mb-2 am pm" id="weather-app">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 mt-3">
            <form id="city-search-form">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter city name"
                id="search-field"
              />
              <input type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let now = new Date();
let currentDate = document.getElementById("date-element");

let date = now.getDate();
let hours = now.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0  ");

let minutes = now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");

let days = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
];
let day = days[now.getDay()];

let months = [
  "January",
  "Febuary",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December",
];
let month = months[now.getMonth()];
currentDate.innerHTML = `${day}, ${month} ${date},  ${hours}:${minutes}`;

function glow() {
  let app = document.getElementById("weather-app");
  if (hours > 6 && hours < 16) {
    app.classList.add("am");
  } else {
    if (hours < 6 && hours >= 16) {
      app.classList.add("pm");
    }
  }
}
glow()
```

I have tried so many different variations of the above code, but since I'm a complete beginner at coding, I feel that I may not know something that can help me with this deliemma. I would appreciate any guidance and if you could try and keep it basic and simple, I would appreciate it, as I'm still learning.

I apologize in advance if I did not post enough information about my problem, or perhaps I included too much unnecessary information- either way, sorry in advance!

Thanks again!

Comment: Remove the other class

Comment: Thanks Konrad! I didn't understand what you meant, but another individual further explained your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to call the `glow` function. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Unfortunately, I did call it, and it didn't work :(
(I just didn't include it here). I will include it so that others know. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1):

As Konrad mentioned you will need to remove the am and pm class from the HTML, otherwise you can't add the correct one, as it will have both.
Furthermore, there is a small issue in the else part of the if statement of glow where:

```
if (hours < 6 && hours >= 16) {
  app.classList.add("pm");
}
```

Meaning that it is only pm if hours is under 6, and over 16 at the same time, which is never true. But since the first if statement, you can simply remove the if-statement in the else-clause, which would fix 'glow'

```
function glow() {
  let app = document.getElementById("weather-app");
  if (hours > 6 && hours < 16) {
    app.classList.remove("pm");
    app.classList.add("am");
  } else {
    app.classList.remove("am");
    app.classList.add("pm");
  }
}
```

sidenote, is am not `hours < 12` ?

Comment: Thank you so so much Blach15! It worked. To be honest, I wasn't too sure how to implement what Konrad mentioned, but when you provided the coding, it made perfect sense. Thanks again! Also, yes you are right, am is <12 (haha), I was just trying to experiment with JS a bit :)